# The p value of F test for the overall (Stage1+Stage2)

Tags: r

The following is the lm result.I want the p value of F test for the overall piecewise linear curves (Stage1+Stage2). I see the F test in lm result: p-value: 7.142e-08, while the F test in linearHypothesis: p-value: 0.01951 *. I want to know which one I should look at? Thanks.

```
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)
score <- c(35, 40, 45, 59, 62, 71, 78, 65, 78, 82, 89, 85, 78, 88, 96, 98)

stage1 <- year - 2000
stage2 <- (year - 2008) * (year >= 2008)
fm <- lm(score ~ stage1 + stage2)
summary(fm)
```

### ## Call:

## lm(formula = score ~ stage1 + stage2)

##

## Residuals:

##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max

## -10.2845  -2.9363  -0.7105   3.9286   8.4312

##

## Coefficients:

##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

## (Intercept)  37.8653     3.4952  10.834 7.05e-08 ***

## stage1        5.2839     0.6578   8.032 2.14e-06 ***

## stage2       -3.2470     1.2715  -2.554    0.024 *

## ---

## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

##

## Residual standard error: 5.861 on 13 degrees of freedom

## Multiple R-squared:  0.9205,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9082

## F-statistic: 75.22 on 2 and 13 DF,  p-value: 7.142e-08

```
library(car)

linearHypothesis(fm, "stage1 + stage2", verbose = TRUE)
```

### ## Hypothesis matrix:

##                 (Intercept) stage1 stage2

## stage1 + stage2           0      1      1

##

## Right-hand-side vector:

## *rhs*

##     0

##

## Estimated linear function (hypothesis.matrix %*% coef - rhs)

## stage1 + stage2

##         2.03696

##

##

## Estimated variance of linear function

## [1] 0.5848974

##

## Linear hypothesis test

##

## Hypothesis:

## stage1  + stage2 = 0

##

## Model 1: restricted model

## Model 2: score ~ stage1 + stage2

##

##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)

## 1     14 690.27

## 2     13 446.58  1    243.69 7.0939 0.01951 *

## ---

## Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

```
plot(score ~ year)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ year, col = "red")
abline(v = 2008, lty = 2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHIGZ.png)

I have used lm function.
I see the F test in lm result: p-value: 7.142e-08, while the F test in linearHypothesis: p-value: 0.01951 *. I want to know which one I should look at? Thanks.